# send image from flutter web to python flask API

Tags: flutter-web

i want to send an image from gallery to a python flask API
it work in android, but i got error "Error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace" when run in chrome

the error "Error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace" appear after print("test 2"); so i think there is some trouble in the add request. maybe there is another specific way for flutter web? because it work in android. thankyou

## code

```
Future<http.Response> getRecommendation(File file, String link) async {
String filename = file.path.split('/').last;
var request = http.MultipartRequest(
  'POST',
  Uri.parse(link),
);

print("test 1");
Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"};
print("test 2");
request.files.add(
  http.MultipartFile(
    'image',
    file.readAsBytes().asStream(),
    file.lengthSync(),
    filename: filename,
  ),
);
print("test 3");
request.headers.addAll(headers);
var res = await request.send();
var response = await http.Response.fromStream(res);
return response;
}
```

Comment: which plugin you are using for selecting the image from gallery?

Comment: @viJaySingh i'm using image picker

  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  image_picker_for_web: ^2.1.10

Comment: can u try with http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(). ... u can pass fileBytes from d selected file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use FilePicker plugin with type image. Change is in the multipart file. Here is a snippet.

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
          type: FileType.image,
          allowCompression: true);
      if (result != null) {
        if (kIsWeb) {
          fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
        }else
          filePath = result.files.first.path;

        fileName = result.files.single.name;
      }

var multipartFile;
      if (kIsWeb) {
        multipartFile = MultipartFile.fromBytes(fileBytes,
            contentType: new MediaType("image", "jpg"),
            filename: fileName);
      } else {
          multipartFile = MultipartFile.fromFileSync(filePath,
            contentType: new MediaType("image", "jpg"),
            filename: fileName);
      }
```

Comment: thankyou for the solution, i've tried it and it works..
but how to display the image i already picked for the web? when i use imagepicker i can use Image.network(path), but it doesn't work when i use filepicker

Comment: You can use fileBytes itself.. using Image.memory(fileBytes)